# An explanation about base..ctor()

Tags: c#

I'm getting an application from my friends to develop. Then in the code I got confusing code like this:

```
public someNameHere()
{
   base..ctor();
}
```

Well I've never had an application like this. I need an explanation for this

> base..ctor();

I've googling and can't find answer that satisfy me. I appreciate for any help you give me.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error to me

Comment: In C#, there is no such syntax. Base class constructors are called like `public MyCtor() : base()`.

Comment: This will not compile, ain't it? Additionally, I don't think you can access a real ctor of base class in this rude way.

Comment: It looks like something copied from disassembler... In any case this line is not needed because empty base constructor is called implicity.

Comment: This looks like the output of a decompiler. In IL a call to the base class constructor is indeed invoked like this. Look for a better decompiler to "get" the code from your friends :-)

Comment: Looks like MSIL syntax. May be it's a code written directly with MSIL?

Comment: @all I got the code like the way it is and yes I can't compile that. and there's a bunch of this ctor() things.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.ctor()` is the internal name used by constructors. It is not used that way in C#, and does not compile. More typically, `base..ctor()` is only used by the compiler when doing things like:

```
public class Foo : Bar {
    public Foo(string s) : base(s) {...} 
    public Foo() {...} // has an implicit :base()
}
```

The only times I've seen that done differently is when decompiling (via reflector etc) some non-C# IL that does the construction code in a different sequence to how the C# compiler does it, which is therefore not expressable in "pure" C#. In raw IL (and from C++ etc) you can call the base-constructor *at any point* in the constructor - not just at the start.

Comment: so in that case you say that my friend gave me the source code from decompiling result?

Comment: @HaritsFadillah quite possibly; that certainly isn't valid C#

Answer (score 3):

Should be the default parameterless constructor of your base class. 
Elaborating, `.ctor()` is the alias for constructor automatically generated compiling C#. So Writing `base..ctor()` is referencing the `.ctor()` method in the base class.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, instead of just a single line comment.

Comment: It's enough for the questioner to google for more information, surely?

Comment: @Poldie So is this what Stackoverflow is about? Giving short answers, just barely enough so the questioner can google the rest?

Comment: Sometimes a long, detailed answer makes sense.  Other times, the questioner clearly needs to read up on the subject; in this case constructors - the syntax, how and why they're used.  Unless you feel up to writing another tutorial on the subject, enabling them to search for one using relevant terms would appear to be the perfect answer.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow I agree with 2