# What is base..ctor(); in C#?

Tags: c#, radix

I am disassembling some C# applications and I am trying to reconstruct the source code. I am disassembling the application along with the required DLLs.
I keep coming across this line `base..ctor();` which gives me an error. The line occurs in some voids with in some subclasses of `Stream` and `Exception`.

Does anyone have any idea what the code should be? I am thinking the disassembler messed it up some how and it is clearly invalid code.
So does anyone know what it is meant to mean and how I can change the line so it works?

Here is the code of one of the subclasses that line occurs in:

```
[Guid("ebc25cf6-9120-4283-b972-0e5520d0000E")]
public class ZlibException : Exception
{
    public ZlibException()
    {
        base..ctor();
        return;
    }

    public ZlibException(string s)
    {
        base..ctor();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164229/an-explanation-about-base-ctor) previous thread will help?

Comment: did you dissasemble the constructors as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be :

```
[Guid("ebc25cf6-9120-4283-b972-0e5520d0000E")]
public class ZlibException : Exception
{
    public ZlibException() : base()
    {
        return;
    }

    public ZlibException(string s) : base()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Which calls the constructor with that signature on the base implementation of this class.

But by default the .NET CLR calls the base, blank constructor for you, so you don't actually need the `: base()`

Answer (score 5):

It's calling the base constructor, your decompiler is just showing it strangely. In IL, constructors are called `.ctor` for short, so when directly reading the IL, your decompiler is apparently confused and thinks this is just another method.

The actual code would look like:

```
public class ZlibException : Exception
{
    public ZlibException() : base();
    {
        return;
    }

    public ZlibException(string s) : base();
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ρσݥzση Sorry, I typed it up incorrectly at first. I've corrected it since then.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking that the code is obfuscated just out of curiosity this `*(&(variable))` does nothing to the variable right? I know `*` gets the contents of a pointer and `&` returns the address of a variable to the above code would do nothing, just pointless obfuscation code to confuse a reader right?

Comment: @ρσݥzση Probably, but I'm really not sure. You could try asking that as another question, but just as a word of warning, SO usually doesn't respond well to questions about obfuscated code. You'll have to phrase the question carefully if you want to avoid any down votes. What decompiler are you using BTW?